# Varnish: show original 500 error page

Tags: varnish

Can I configure Varnish in such a way it shows the original page from the backend when the backend throws a 500 error page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the default. I have some `if (beresp.status == 500)` in it :s

Comment: Great question. But I need more from your answer. Mine has some if (beresp.status == 500) as well, and I assume you need to do something in that case. How then do you deliver the original back end 500 error page?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to show the original 500 error only in some environments, like development.

If so, then you can assign Varnish an identity:

```
$ varnishd -i development
```

And then check that identity in your VCL:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  if (server.identity ~ "^development") {
    return (deliver);
  }

  if (beresp.status == 500) {
    # ...
  }
}
```